# How to catch std::variant holding wrong type in compile-time?

Tags: c++, variant, visitor-pattern

I have following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <variant>

using namespace std;

template <class... Ts>
struct overloaded : Ts...
{
    using Ts::operator()...;
};
template <class... Ts>
overloaded(Ts...)->overloaded<Ts...>;

using element_dict = std::map<string, string>;
using element_type = std::variant<string, element_dict, int>;

void foo(element_type elements)
{
    std::visit(overloaded{
            [](string element) { cout << "string\n"; },
            [](element_dict element) { cout << "dict\n";},
            [](auto /*elements*/) { throw std::runtime_error("wrong type"); }
        }, elements);
}

int main()
{
    element_type str_elems = "string_elem";
    foo(str_elems);
    element_type dict_elems = element_dict{ {"string", "string"} };
    foo(dict_elems);
    element_type wrong_type_elems = 5;
    foo(wrong_type_elems); // throws error

    return 0;
}
```

stdout :

```
string
dict
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: wrong type
```

I have `element_type` containing several types. Basically I consider it to contain `string` and `element_dict`. Here I have situation when somebody added `int` type to `element_type`, but forgot to provide required fixes to `foo` function. Now I detect this situation in run-time throwing exception. Is there any way to detect it in compile-time?

Comment: Yes.  Remove the `[](auto /*elements*/)` overload.  That overload "converts" a compile-time error to a runtime exception.

Comment: Why do you think you need the 3rd overload anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get that situation to fail at compile-time is to simply not include the overload lambda that catches non-`string` and non-`element_dict` typed items; that is, remove

```
[](auto /*elements*/) { throw std::runtime_error("wrong type"); }
```

Then it will fail at compile-time. Basically, by including that case, you are specifically telling the compiler that you want it to succeed at compiling such cases; you are opting-in to behavior you don't want.